# How to use batch SQL in JDBC with PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting this error while executing my code, which is supposed to process SQL statements in batch mode:

> ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

This is the code, that when run, generates the error:

```
public class Login {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            Driver driver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            System.out.println("coneecting to the database:");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "pass");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("creating statement");
            String sql = "insert into shweta values(?,?)";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            printrows(stmt);

            stmt.setString(1, "love");
            stmt.setInt(2, 45);
            stmt.addBatch();

            stmt.setString(1, "kaun");
            stmt.setInt(2, 29);
            stmt.addBatch();

            int count[] = st.executeBatch();

            con.commit();

            printrows(stmt);

            // printRs(rs);

            st.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (con != null)
                    con.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException en) {
                en.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                if (con != null)
                    con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("good bye ashish");
    }

    public static void printrows(Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select * from shweta";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name

            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            String first = rs.getString("auth");

            System.out.print(", Age :    " + age + "\n");
            System.out.print("AUTH :     " + first + "\n");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I am new to coding and am unsure how to resolve this error, all help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the stacktrace? Please add that in your question.

Comment: What is the table definition and what is the stacktrace?

Comment: You are interleaving `executeQuery` calls around your batch SQL calls (when you call `printrows`. That doesn't look right, comment out the `printrow` calls and test your code again.

Comment: hi perception thanks for answer but i comment print rows but still got null pointer exception

Comment: can try with class loader i guess issue is with Driver loading

Answer (score 0):

A user bind or define, or an Oracle function, is not supported by this
heterogeneous SQL*Net connection.
 Upgrade the older version of Oracle and try again.

Comment: at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1051)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:854)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1156)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1315)
 at Login.printrows(Login.java:92)
 at Login.main(Login.java:22)

Comment: table just have two columns 1st is author and 2nd is age

Answer (score 0):

Statement st is not initialized - and used in executeBatch. Statement stmt which is used to insert shouldn't be changed to run another sql inside printrows.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:754)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:219)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:813)

Answer (score 0):

i find out the problem that is causing the code to throw exception.the reason is that i am
   nt intializing my statement as Statement st = con.createstatement(); due to which 
   compiler is throwing error.we cannt pass directly prepared statement object as a parameter to execute the query .so any how we have to use statement and pass its reference to parameter in printrows .